# How can I re-install an app that I am developing after a bad install?

Tags: android

I'm having a bit of a problem here!

I have been successfully installing and uninstalling my app on my phone.  However my most recent install was interrupted when i accidentally removed the wire from my laptop during the installation.

After that I "uninstalled" the app then I tried to re-install it through my laptop via an android studion build.  The result was an error......

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/electrichappiness.com.makemyday"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/rockit.cup.myAppName
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

After doing significant research, I tried...
1. to access the /data/ folder of my phone (which I can see nothing in - my phone is not rooted) in order to delete any remnant files that could be causing an issue
2. Clearing my cache for all of my apps 
3. Re-installing over it (always fails)
4. I tried to rename my app files and signature in order to have it register as a different app (no change oddly)

I have read many of the posts on stackoverflow but cannot figure out how to solve my problem.  Any ideas?

From my logcat:

```
07-11 07:44:58.703  29261-29261/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-11 07:44:58.703  29261-29261/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-11 07:44:58.773     710-1512/? D/PackageManager﹕ installPackage , uri:file:, flags:66, installer:null, uid:2000, pid:29261, userId:UserHandle{-1}
07-11 07:44:58.783      710-826/? W/MountService﹕ getVolumeState(/storage/ext_sd): Unknown volume
07-11 07:44:58.783      710-826/? W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:
07-11 07:44:58.803      710-826/? W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:
07-11 07:44:58.803      710-826/? I/PackageManager﹕ Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl117110110
07-11 07:44:59.293      710-826/? W/PackageManager﹕ Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/myFakeCompany.com.myTestApp.apk
07-11 07:44:59.553  17358-29255/? D/AutoSetting﹕ service - handleMessage() stop self
07-11 07:44:59.563  17358-17358/? D/AutoSetting﹕ service - onDestroy() END
07-11 07:44:59.563  17358-29255/? D/AutoSetting﹕ service - handleMessage() quit looper
07-11 07:44:59.994      710-877/? D/PMS﹕ acquireWL(442cea80): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1 710 1000
07-11 07:45:00.064    1140-1140/? D/AppWidgetHostView﹕ updateAppWidget mInfo = AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{ch.bitspin.timely/ch.
```

Comment: The issue you are facing is documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64514)

Comment: Do you know of any way to solve this issue without getting root?

Comment: A factory reset won't help at all. You'll have the same problem. It wasn't only the messed up wire. You messed up your app by not renaming your package name everywhere. Now, there are two separate package names. Not only that, but those two package names don't seem to follow the normal conventions (which shouldn't be a problem, but that usually indicates to me that you've probably made other basic mistakes if you're not the kind of programmers that follows basic Java conventions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is trying to install an app using `adb shell install -r yourapp.apk`  ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data).

You can install the .apk manually from the bin folder using `adb install yourapp.apk` or on another partition `adb install -s yourapp.apk` ('-s' means install on SD card instead of internal storage).

If all fails try rebooting your phone and re-running your app from studio.

Okay here goes nothing.. All possible options I could think of:

```
 1. Install              : `adb install appname.apk`
 2. Re-Install           : `adb install -r appname.apk`
 3. SDCard               : `adb install -s appname.apk`
 4. Clear Package        : `adb shell pm clear PACKAGE-NAME`
 5. Remove data          : `adb shell; cd /data/data/; rm -r PACKAGE_NAME`
 6. Forward lock Install : `adb push appname.apk /sdcard/; adb shell pm install -l /sdcard/appname.apk;`
 7. (Up/Down)grade API   : `Re-Compile the app and try installation.`

 *. Factory Reset (LAST RESORT)**

 *. User Resolution      : `I had to completely re-write my app as a new project under android studio to fix the problem.`
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not solve my problem.  Same result whether I install manually or via android studio

Comment: Try removing the existing data from /data/data  like so `adb shell; cd /data/data/; rm -r <PACKAGE_NAME>`

Comment: hmm, I do not see my package in that folder location.

Comment: Tricky one. The way I see this is Android is trying to preserve your data even after package deletion. Try `adb shell pm clear <PACKAGE-NAME>` or I'd suggest two options 1. Downgrade/Upgrade your API version from the Android Studio and re-run/re-install the app with that. 2. Perform a factory reset.(Last resort)

Comment: After running that it states "Failed".  I also tried recreating the app under a different project name (thereby renaming all of the top level classes).  Same result. Im not looking forward to a factory reset....

Comment: Wait before I investigate more.. did you try `adb install -r <appname>` ??

Comment: I have tried it, but I keep getting told that it cannot find the apk file.  What I did was open "terminal" in my android studio, then typed "adb install -s <appname>" and "adb install -r <appname>" where appname is the direct path to the apk file, including the .apk file.  The apk file the app-debug.apk that is generated when I build the app from android studio

Comment: Haven't used terminal on Studio much but why don't you try using Command Prompt ?? Also, the .apk file should be located in /bin folder with just the appname.apk in your workspace.

Comment: I dont think that its actually creating the apk file.  the only apk I see is "app-debug.apk".  I checked into my log cat and saw (added to the question).  I also just commented out all of my google login code.

Comment: I had to completely re-write my app as a new project under android studio to fix the problem.  but its been solved.

Comment: Cool. Now you know the solution to the most difficult problem ;)